# Determine "correct" data based on multiple sources

Tags: outliers

I tried searching for this but might be missing some important keywords as I could not find anything.

---

Data Available :
I have 1 to 4 sources of data showing temperature for various locations on a given day and do not know the actual temperature.

Example:

City, type, Country, Source_1, Source_2, Source_3, Source_4

- Toronto, urban, Canada, 19, 19, 21, null
- Paris, urban, France, 21, 22, 22, 21
- New York, urban, USA, 25, 26, 32, null
- BlahBlahTown, urban, USA, 21, null, null, null
- BlahBlahTownx2, urban, USA, null, null, 21, null

---

Goal: If possible, determine a fairly accurate temperature for each location.

---

Problem: 
When there are 3 or 4 sources of data, I can imagine that it would not be too hard to calculate a good guess for temperature. Ideas are welcome here as well but my job is a bit easier as I don't need 100% accuracy, Toronto @ 19 to 21 and Paris @ 21 or 22 are good enough. My problem is trying to determine for locations with only 1 source of data, whether this information is reliable.

---

My Plan:
My plan is to determine for each location with multiple sources of data, which sources were "correct" and which ones were "wrong". I would then use this information and some additional data such as country and location type to determine the validity of the source data.

So in the example above, source_1 would be reliable for BlahBlahTown given that for other urban locations in the united states, it was *fairly accurate.* however, this could not be said for source_3 and BlahBlahTownx2.

---

Questions:
Is there a statistical approach I could use to help with my definition of *fairly accurate* ?

I have currently proceeded with a business logic originated 20% rule meaning that the source is accurate for a given location as long as there is another source within 20%.

Comment: Unless you make some (fairly strong) assumptions, you have no information at all about accuracy!  The dispersion among multiple observations tells you something about how much they might differ, but even when they perfectly agree it's possible they are all always, simultaneously, and woefully wrong.  If you're willing to assume the sources tend to be accurate *everywhere* and (therefore) the deviations among them reflect imprecision, then the answer depends on how *independent* you assume the observations to be (conditional on the underlying true temperature).

Comment: BTW, a relative figure like "20%" makes sense only for *absolute* temperatures.  That's around $\pm 50$ degrees Celsius for these cities.  That doesn't sound very accurate at all.

Comment: Many temperature measurements are needed for forcasting. If one has many, one procedure would be to interpolate temperatures on a 32 km grid for forcasting at midrange (12h to 120h) e.g., see [link](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/MWR-D-16-0413.1).

Comment: Thanks for the comments @whuber.

A true assumption is that sources tend to be accurate most places but exceptions exist and I am trying to find those exceptions. 

As for the second assumption on dependency, is this from location to location within a data source or source to source?

location: There are not independent as the method for calculating the data varies within each source per type and country variables.
source: These are likely not independent given that they are all measuring the same "true" temperature.

Comment: The problem with exceptions to accuracy is that--depending on why they occur--*all* your data sources may simultaneously be inaccurate by unknown amounts.